# configure the live migration policy of VMs to another physical host whenever the capacity of the VM can not be increased on the existing physical host

Tags: migration, cloud, virtual-machine, free

-configure the live migration policy of VMs to another physical host whenever the capacity of the VM can not be increased on the existing physical host.
This is about Cloud Computing.
Project: Build your virtual private cloud on any one of the following cloud platform: AWS cloud /Google cloud/ IBM cloud / Microsoft Azure and do the following. Confirm the cloud platform on which you will work by returning an email to me.

1. Create one public subnet and one private subnet. Configure a virtual Internet gateway and the virtual router accordingly.
2. Host your MySQL/Oracle/any relational database in RDS. The database host should belong to a private subnet that is not accessible directly from the Internet.
3. create a virtual machine (VM) instance and host your web application on it. Create a replica of this instance also.  The VMs must belong to the public subnet and directly accessible from the internet.

(3A) Develop any one application of your choice with limited functionality and database use. This application will be hosted on the VM. You can select the application and functionality of your choice that you wish to develop and confirm the same with me by replying to this email and I will approve the same.
(OR)
(3A)  Develop any cloud service and host it on the VM. You can select the cloud service of your choice that you wish to develop and  confirm the same with me by replying to this email and I will approve the same.

4. create a load balancer and assign the VMs to it.
5. Configure scaling policy such that whenever the average CPU utilization across all VMs exceeds 65 percent then one new VMs must be added and whenever the CPU utilization drops to 15%, one VM must be stopped and removed.
6. configure security policy such that users of the newly created "Dbusers" group  can only access the database and users of the "AppAdmin" group can only access the VMs.
7. configure the live migration policy of VMs to another physical host whenever the capacity of the VM can not be increased on the existing physical host. (This point can be discussed theoretically if cant be implemented practically due to restriction applied in free tier)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one public subnet and one private subnet. Configure a virtual Internet gateway and the virtual router accordingly.
   Link: https://fb.watch/23cNJ8bWyH/
2. Host your MySQL/Oracle/any relational database in RDS. The database host should belong to a private subnet that is not accessible directly from the Internet.
   Link: https://fb.watch/23cLn0Gi81/
3. create a virtual machine (VM) instance and host your web application on it. Create a replica of this instance also.  The VMs must belong to the public subnet and directly accessible from the internet.

(3A) Develop any one application of your choice with limited functionality and database use. This application will be hosted on the VM. You can select the application and functionality of your choice that you wish to develop and confirm the same with me by replying to this email and I will approve the same.
Link: https://fb.watch/23cN4mKfOu/

4. create a load balancer and assign the VMs to it.
   link: https://fb.watch/23cMcHWwQX/
5. Configure scaling policy such that whenever the average CPU utilization across all VMs exceeds 65 percent then one new VMs must be added and whenever the CPU utilization drops to 15%, one VM must be stopped and removed.
   Link :https://fb.watch/23cJN5B--1/
6. configure security policy such that users of the newly created "Dbusers" group  can only access the database and users of the "AppAdmin" group can only access the VMs.
   Link: https://fb.watch/24milhMY61/